# Can arrows with different target and source be identical?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that we are working in a category $C$ whose arrows are certain set-functions. It seems possible that an arrow $f$ from $c_1$ to $c_2$ is the same function as an arrow $g$ from $c_3$ to $c_4$ ($c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ are objects of $C$, $c_1$ and $c_3$ are different objects, $c_2$ and $c_4$ are also different) set-theoretically speaking. Do $f$ and $g$ count as the same arrow?

Comment: No. By definition, they are different arrows, since a function consists of three pieces of data: (1) a source, (2) a target, and (3) a rule associating an element of the target to each element of the source. Clearly, both of conditions (1) and (2) in the definition of these functions are different.

Comment: Perhaps you have a specific example in mind of two functions that *feel* like they are the same? One can invent looser notions of *sameness* that might identify them, but they are not identical in the original category, again *by definition*.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks! I also think that they are not the same in the category-theoretic sense. But they are the same function in the sense that they are the same set (set-functions are just sets of some ordered pairs). For example, we might have two structures $(G,\cdot)$ and $(H,\ast)$ and a homomorphism $f$ between them. We might also have $(G,\cdot')$ and $(H,\ast')$ and a homomorphism $g$ between them. $f$ and $g$ have different sources and targets but they could be the same set.

Comment: Ahhhh. I get what you're saying now. These are objects in a category $\mathcal{C}$ that admits a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ but it's not faithful so the category is not [*concretizable*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Concrete_categories).

Comment: It's still the case that the arrows $f$ and $g$ in their respective set of morphisms are *distinct*, but their *images* in $\mathsf{Set}$ are the same. To clarify your setup: if you name the functor $U: \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$, then on objects $U(c_1) = U(c_3)$ and $U(c_2) = U(c_4)$ and the morphisms $U(f) = U(g)$.

Comment: @SammyBlack That's not the definition of faithfulness. Faithful functors are required to be injective on each hom-set, but not necessarily on the set of all morphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree with you re the definition of faithful, but how does this address the question. OP is interested in arrows that land in the same hom-set, despite being distinct in the original category. Am I reading the question the same way as you?

Comment: The forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of sets is faithful but also has the property that OP is concerned about: homomorphisms between different groups may have the same underlying map of sets.